# Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_ComboBox autocomplete not working

Tags: autocomplete, dojo, zend-form

Hi all I'm posting this as I can't figure it out.
Basically I have a search page in which I have a Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_Combobox. I want to implement autocomplete functionality for this element but its not working. The search functionality works fine I just have to type in text.

I'm thinking that my problem is with the setup of the autocompleteAction in my controller, I'll be honest I'm not sure how this is setup. I can't get my head around as I'm new to the Zend Framework, the tutorials I've found online and are of a different format to a book I'm reading on the subject.

```
public function autocompleteAction()
{
// disable layout and view rendering
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender(true);

// get list of breed names from the breeds table
$qry = Doctrine_Query::create()
              ->select('b.breed')
              ->from('PetManager_Model_Breeds b');

              $result=$qry->fetchArray();   


   //generate and return JSON string 
   $data = new Zend_Dojo_Data('breed',$result);
   echo $data->toJson();


}
```

In case it is my implementation of The element itself here is the code extract from my form class.

```
// Create a autocomplete inout for breed name
   $breedName = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_ComboBox('breed');
   $breedName->setLabel('Search Breeed Names');
   $breedName->setOptions(array(
        'autocomplete'=>'false',
    'hasDownArrow'=>'true',
    'storeID'=>'breedStore',
    'storeType'=>'dojox.data.QueryReadStore',
    'storeParams'=>array('url'=>"/breeds/breed/autocomplete"),
    'dijitParams' =>array('searchAttr' =>'breed')))
      ->setRequired(true)
      ->addValidator('NotEmpty',true)
      ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')
      ->addFilter('StringToLower')
      ->addFilter('StringTrim');
```

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

I.S.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add a label and specific metadata to your Zend_Dojo_Data object in order to work with the QueryReadStore. Something like this:

```
//generate and return JSON string 
$data = new Zend_Dojo_Data('breed', $result);
$data->setLabel('breed');
$data->setMetadata('numRows', count($result));
echo $data->toJson();
```